# R to Latex with xtable: table must fit the page

Tags: xtable

I am looking for a way to fit a long table (many rows and many columns) into a single A4 page from a Latex document, using the code produced by xtable.

Here is my R code, with resulting table that goes way off the roof. How to parametrize xtable to have this matrix/table fit into one single page ?

Thanks in advance!

Below is the benchmark code

library(xtable)

## Fix number of decimals

specify_decimal <- function(x, k) format(round(x, k), nsmall=k)

# Matrix of results, can be initialized at the beginning

result <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 10)

colnames(result) <- c("Sa", "Mi","Me","JU","Mo","Jp","So","Uo","Np","Pa")

# Initialize result

a <- specify_decimal ( sin (pi/4), 2 )
b <- specify_decimal ( cos (pi/3), 2 )

for (i in 1:10) {

```
result[1,i] <- paste(a,b)
result[2,i] <- paste(a,b)

    }
```

## One set of results for a given day

for (d in 1:10)     {

temp <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 10)

for (i in 1:10) {

```
temp[1,i] <- paste(a,b)
temp[2,i] <- paste(a,b)

    }
```

## Add the new results to the existing matrix of results

result <- rbind(result,temp)

```
        }
```

print(xtable(result, align= "ccccccccccc"),include.rownames=FALSE)